# LINQ - conditional where on datatable

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I've read a few posts about conditional where clauses and Linq. I believe I have implemented this correctly, but when I use Linq the query returns 0 records. However when I use the SQL counterpart of the Linq statement it returns 3 records. Essentially what I would like to do is add an additional where statement provided "sItemID" is not null or empty.

```
from dr in _openOrders.AsEnumerable()
  where dr.Field<Guid>("CatalogID") == Guid.Parse(sCatalogID)
     && dr.Field<Guid>("LocationID") == Guid.Parse(sLocationID)
     && ((string.IsNullOrEmpty(sItemID)) || dr.Field<Guid>("ItemID") == Guid.Parse(sItemID))
select dr;
```

Comment: Can you provide some more data on this? what are the values on the datatable, and the sCatalogID, sLocationId and sItemID values you are using for testing? and the sql query you are running might be helpfull too.

thanks

Comment: can you post the equivalent sql query that you tried ?

Comment: How does the additional `WHERE` looks like? Also if you could share the corresponding SQL statement?

Comment: Found the issue, see my answer to the question. Thanks for the suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it wasn't the LINQ query at all. The datatable refreshes with new data from the database every 5 minutes. I was simply querying against the table for new data before the table was actually updated with new data. It wasn't until my second cup of coffee that I realized that I had written code to do this. Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You're using `((string.IsNullOrEmpty(sItemID)) ||`; this returns TRUE if sItemID **is** null or empty.  Try `!((string.IsNullOrEmpty(sItemID)) ||` instead -- note the leading **`!`**.

Comment: I believe this is intentional. OP wants either `sItemID` to be null/empty, or some column to satisfy condition involving `sItemID` - pretty usual approach in SQL.

Comment: Then I'll have to think about it some more.  Perhaps the condition is: if `sItemID` is null/empty, then where (foobar), else where `dr.Field<Guid>("ItemID") == Guid.Parse(sItemID)`.